# ¿"A indra" o "Indra" se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular?

Tags: gramática

Quisiera preguntar por qué no es “A Indra” sino “Indra” en “[Indra se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular](https://www.elespanol.com/invertia/empresas/tecnologia/20211216/indra-adjudica-contrato-digitalizacion-consular-electronica-millones/634936700_0.html?fbclid=IwAR2sjmGFmWfgjeU6oYPKbbDvtBB6TgAoWlspmDExOGGPBNKRuUwYeRSmIoU)”. ¿No es cierto que “Indra” es sujeto directo en este contexto? ¡Muhcas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ambas oraciones:

1. A Indra se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular.

y

2. Indra se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular.

son correctas, aunque (1) sonaría mejor, sobre todo en un titular, con un orden sintáctico diferente:

1.a. Se adjudica a Indra el gran contrato de la digitalización consular.

Tal como está, (1) solo se usaría para enfatizar el adjudicatario o el contrato adjudicado:

- A Indra, no a XXX, se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular.
- A Indra se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular, no el contrato de la digitalización registral.

Para que la oración no sea enfática, debe usarse (1.a.).

En (1), "se adjudica" es una forma pasiva (= "es adjudicado"), "el gran contrato de la digitalización consular" es sujeto de la pasiva y "a Indra" es objeto indirecto (se puede reemplazar o reforzar con "le"):

1.b. Se **le** adjudica (a Indra) el gran contrato de la digitalización consular. (El contrato le es adjudicado.)

En (2), como bien dice la otra respuesta, "se adjudica" es un verbo pronominal equivalente a "resultar adjudicatario de" (o sea, "ganar", normalmente en el contexto de una licitación). En este caso, "Indra" es sujeto. En lugar de "se adjudica", podríamos decir:

3. Indra resulta adjudicataria del gran contrato de la digitalización consular.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones también!

Comment: Otra posibilidad sería "Adjudicado a Indra el gran contrato de la digitalización consular".

Answer (score -1):

https://dle.rae.es/adjudicar

> AJUDICARSE
> prnl. En ciertas competiciones, ganar algo. El equipo se adjudicó el campeonato.

Porque "Indra se adjudica el gran contrato de la digitalización consular” quiere decir ganó el contrato.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Comment: downvoters: tsk, tsk, tsk

Comment: Please cite verbatim reproductions of text properly, i.e., make it clear where they start, where they end, and where they come from. Not doing that is plagiarism, which is not tolerated here.